# extract rows from csv where first column value matches first column values in another file (bash/awk/sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two csv files:

#source.txt

```
"some_id","some_value","1"
"some_id2","some_value2","2"
"some_id3","some_value3","3"
"some_id4","some_value4","4"
"some_id5","some_value5","5"
```

I have another file

target.txt

```
"some_id3"
"some_id4"
<...>
```

I would like an intersection between the two files on the first column alone, so the result I am looking for is:

```
"some_id3","some_value3","3"
"some_id4","some_value4","4"
```

I can write something in python but the source file is 30GB so I was thinking something using awk/sed would be much faster.

on the first field, which is the field of interest on both files, there are no embedded quotes or anything funny. It is a simple string.

Comment: can any of these fields include embedded newlines or embedded/escaped double quotes? if the answer is 'yes' then please update the question to show some samples

Comment: which of the 2 inputs is the *`source file`*? how big (MBytes) is the small(er) file?

Comment: @markp-fuso answered both your questions. the first field has nothing funny in it. The other fields may or maybe not contain embedded/escaped double quotes.

Comment: Are the files ordered? Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: @JamesBrown thank you for not downvoting. if you mean are the contents sorted in any way, no, they are not.

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

If we don't have to worry about embedded double quotes or embedded linefeeds:

```
$ join -t'"' -j2 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6 <(sort -t'"' -k2,2n source.csv) <(sort -t'"' -k2,2n target.csv)
"some_id3","some_value3","3
"some_id4","some_value4","4
```

If we don't have to worry about embedded linefeeds:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" } FNR==NR { id[$2]; next } $2 in id' target.csv source.csv
"some_id3","some_value3","3"
"some_id4","some_value4","4"
```

Handling embedded linefeeds will require a bit more coding effort and/or use of software designed to handle csv files.  This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535) (referenced in a comment to your previous question) references a few ideas for parsing a csv file that includes embedded linefeeds.  Once you get the parsing (of embedded linefeeds) figured out then the 'join' of the two files should be (relatively) easy.